# Can we access the benchmarking report/data from Google Analytics reporting API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I am trying to access the Google analytics data for [Benchmarking reports](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6086676?hl=en&ref_topic=6086651) via API or programmatically

I couldn't find this in the reporting API or metadata API. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The google analytics website uses the Google analytics api to get its data. So as long as you find the exact same [dimensions and metrics](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/) you used in the report you are talking about then yes you could recreate the report using the Reporting API.  Some of the reports contain calculated fields which you will have to calculate yourself by requesting the data that is needed for the calculation in order to get the correct results.

If you want the actual results to be computed for you and see the graph itself the answer is no.  The api is just raw data you have to do all the calculations and display yourself.

Comment: My question specifically asks for the benchmark (industry) data not my own. I can query them with the parameters I know that but I don't find the industry or demographic benchmarks which can tell me how I am performing against the rest of the world.

Comment: That kind of data isnt part of google analytics that api isn't going to return that to you.  The google analytics api only returns "your" data and the calculations based upon that.

Comment: Ah okay. I thought if they did provide it on the dashboard, there must be some way to fetch that part as well. If there is some third party benchmark or a way to get them, can you point me to that direction?

Comment: The google analytics website is not the google analytics api the api only returns your data.  What the website team has chosen to analyzes on is out of scope for the API.  No i cant help you with third party applications.